# How to replace with an exception

Tags: replacement

I would like to replace the following expression:

```
sp[p1, p1] + 2*sp[p1, p1]*sp[p2, p2] /. sp[p1, p1] -> sp[p2, p2]
```

BUT I do not want to replace the second term only the first. BTW, the `sp` stands for "scalar product" in my notation.

Comment: `ReplacePart` might be useful for this.

Comment: The above example is fairly easy. My actual expression is much more complicated thats why I need a rule to replace sp[p1,p1]->sp[p2,p2] but I should not replace the combination of the two scalarproducts.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify this requirement.

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = sp[p1, p1] + 2*sp[p1, p1]*sp[p2, p2];

rules = {pat : HoldPattern[Times[___, _sp, ___, __sp, ___]] :> pat, 
        sp[p1, p1] -> sp[p2, p2]};

ReplaceAll[rules] @ expr
```

> ```
>  sp[p2, p2] + 2 sp[p1, p1] sp[p2, p2]
> ```

#### [`ReplaceAll >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One can use [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) with a level specification:

```
Replace[sp[p1, p1] + 2*sp[p1, p1]*sp[p2, p2], sp[p1, p1] -> sp[p2, p2], 1]
```

---

For [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html) mentioned in the comment by @DanielLichtblau:

```
ReplacePart[sp[p1, p1] + 2*sp[p1, p1]*sp[p2, p2], 1 -> sp[p2, p2]]
```